# Validate nested object in Jackson

Tags: java, json, spring, validation, jackson

Ive got a spring project and using jackson for json serialization and deserialization.

And I have these DTOs defined,

CertManDTO,

```
public class CertManDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id;

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    private UUID certificateId;

    @NotNull
    private Long orgId;

    @NotNull
    private CertificateType certificateType;

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    @NotNull
    private PublicCertificateDTO publicCertificate;

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private PrivateCertificateDTO privateCertificate;

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    private ZonedDateTime expiryDate;

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    private ZonedDateTime createdDate;

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    private ZonedDateTime updatedDate;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

PublicCertificateDTO,

```
public class PublicCertificateDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    @NotNull
    private String certificate;

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    @NotNull
    private String dnsZone;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

PrivateCertificateDTO,

```
public class PrivateCertificateDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private String pkcs12;

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private String privateCertificatePassword;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

You can see above that I have set I have `@NotNull` annotation set for the fields `certificate` & `dnzZone`.

However posting this JSON seems to parse successfully. This only happens on nested objects.

```
{  
   "orgId":"1001",
   "certificateType":"Single Use",
   "privateCertificate":{  
      "pkcs12":"test",
      "certificatePassword":"Test"
   },
   "publicCertificate":{  

   }
}
```

If I post the following it will fail the validation as `@NotNull` is set for `publicCertificate`

```
{  
   "orgId":"1001",
   "certificateType":"Single Use",
   "privateCertificate":{  
      "pkcs12":"test",
      "certificatePassword":"Test"
   }
}
```

I do have `@Valid` set for the `@RequestBody` in the `RestController`.

Any idea what could be causing this ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you forgot to add `@Valid` annotation to your nested DTOs. Try the following code:

```
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
@NotNull
@Valid
private PublicCertificateDTO publicCertificate;
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I posted the question I came across this [blog post](https://huynt.wordpress.com/2012/08/09/jsr-303-bean-validation-nested-validation/) about bean validation. You need to `@Valid` to validate the nested objects.

Hence refactored CertManDTO as,

```
public class CertManDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id;

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    private UUID certificateId;

    @NotNull
    private Long orgId;

    @NotNull
    private CertificateType certificateType;

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    @NotNull
    @Valid
    private PublicCertificateDTO publicCertificate;

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private PrivateCertificateDTO privateCertificate;

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    private ZonedDateTime expiryDate;

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    private ZonedDateTime createdDate;

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    private ZonedDateTime updatedDate;

    // Getters and setters
}
```